# Visual Studio 2012 find and replace highlight color is not exact

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Ok, I am using the Visual Studio 2012 Color Theme Editor extension and I have modified the dark theme a little bit so that it suits my needs.

However I am experiencing an issue with the background color when I am using the Find tool. The issue is that I am setting an exact color for the background of the highlighted string, but it seems that there is some default transparency applied which is not editable even when using the editor mentioned above (VS gives you the option to edit the colors while the custom editor gives you the option to change the opacity as well).

Since I am using the dark theme whichever color I choose it looks like dark grey with a little bit of red/blue/yellow/whatever. I need to set it to something vibrant and not to dark grey with a drop of white for example - I want to easily see what is highlighted when I search.

How do I set it to something vibrant and not to dark grey with a drop of white for example - I want to easily see what is highlighted when I search?

Comment: And the question is? [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)